# Smoothing a 3 dimensional Euclidean space matrix

Tags: math, computer-vision, bezier, smoothing

I have a general question about what method to use for smoothing a 3D (xyz) grid.

My program has large matrixes of 3D points obtained with a stereovision method.  The shape of the result is always something like a semisphere, but it has a rugosity due to stereovision errors I want to eliminate.

The question is, how to do it?  Rigth now I have half developed a method for soomthing, but I think there may be a better method.

My actual idea is to use Hermite method. The idea is to:

1. Take all XY and smooth in two directions ->XYnew and XnewY
2. Convert the Hermite lines into Bezier lines and find the cross point between XYnew and XnewY, having the new point. (Repeat with all points, normally 2000)
3. Use hermite XYZ smoothing having XYZnew.

Rigth now I have the hermite surface smoothing and hermite line smoothing inplemented in C++, but the middle part is not as easy as espected.

Anyway, my question is, is this a correct method or is there another one which may be better?

Of course the idea is to elliminate the error generated by the stereovision method, this is not a computer graphics problem, is more a data treatment problem

Appendix:

At first I thougth that with a Z smoothing would be suficient, but clearly it is not, there is also a lot of XY error. In the images below you can see the Z fitting working but still it is really rugous as it can be seen in the 2 image. (The colours are deformations and shoul be quite continous)
[image: Image without Z smoothing]
[image]

Comment: Bezier curve is two dimensional and using it for smoothing 3 dimensional surface is at least not effective. Also your data doesn't really look that noisy, did you try to simply apply moving average or local regression using weighted linear least squares for smoothing?

Comment: I know it has not a lot of noise, but it is enough not to be good. The colours (calculated from deformations of the squares) must be soft, all that small blue and red random solitary points are for sure stereo vision errors. I didn't try to make local regression, but I think treating lines separately may actually generate more error in some cases. Still I have to read more about methods, but it seems that @Franco's option is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have better priors, it's hard to beat the classic Taubin's algorithm: http://mesh.brown.edu/taubin/pdfs/taubin-iccv95a.pdf

Comment: Which is roughly the same as applying Gaussian smoothing.

Comment: The thing is I also need to extract reliable information from the result of the smoothing, do you think that Taubin's algorithm will not filter too much my data? Of course I can see that if I use Gaussian smoothing, instead of eliminating the error generated in the stereovision I am going to create more error because the amount the filter modify the result, but does Taubin's algorithm really works as a low pass filter and is only going to eliminate de high frequencies of my data? It seems OK reading the paper, but I just want to be sure before I implement it in c++ ...

Comment: Well I am giving your answer as valid even though I won't probably use it. It really is a nice algorithm and would work pretty nice on smoothing surfaces.